# Handling spaces with 'cp'

Tags: bash

I've got an external drive with over 1TB of project files on it. I need to reformat this drive so I can reorganize it, however before I do that I need to transfer everything. The issue is I'm on a Mac and the drive is formatted as NTFS so all I can do is copy from it. I have tried to simply just copy and paste in Finder but the drive seems to lock up after roughly 15 min of copying that way. So I decided to write a bash script to iterate through the all 1000+ files one at a time. This seems to work for files that are without spaces but skips when it hits one.

Here is what I've hacked together so far.. I'm not too advanced in bash so any suggestions would be great on how you handle the spaces.

```
quota=800
size=`du -sg /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP`
files="/Volumes/Lacie/EXR_files/*"

for file in $files
do
    if [[ ${size%%$'\t'*} -lt $quota ]];
    then
        echo still under quota;
        cp -v $file /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP_EXR;
        du -sg /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP_EXR;
    else
        echo over quota;
    fi
done
```

(I'm checking for directory size because I'm having to split this temporary copy onto a few different place before I copy it all back onto the one reformatted drive.)

Comment: you don't need those semicolons if you have a new-line chars.

Comment: @Parker - here's a great [tutorial on quotes in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)

Comment: You might want to try `rsync`, it supports resuming.

Comment: @Thor yeah ended up giving rsync a try after about an hour in - the progress percentage for each file is a very nice visual to have!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope I'm  not misunderstanding.  If you have problem with space character in filename, **quote it**. If you want bash to expand parameters inside it, use double quote.

```
cp -v "$file" /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP_EXR
```

Comment: Oh wow, thats great.. Thanks man. I'm always overlooking tiny details like that.

Comment: happens to me too. :) 

If it solves your problem please *accept* the answer.

Comment: Quoting `$file` won't help; spaces will split such filenames into two while expanding `$files`, so `file` will never get the whole file name.

Comment: @chepner thats wrong. It certainly works. Did you even try it?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I see now that it does. My apologies. I forgot that `files` is a pattern containing a literal '*', not a list of file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the file names in an array, then iterate over that.

```
quota=800
size=`du -sg /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP`
files=( /Volumes/Lacie/EXR_files/* )

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
    if [[ ${size%%$'\t'*} -lt $quota ]];
    then
        echo still under quota;
        cp -v "$file" /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP_EXR;
        du -sg /Users/work/Desktop/TEMP_EXR;
    else
        echo over quota;
    fi
done
```

The two things to note are 1) quoting the array expansion in the for list, and 2) quoting `$file` for the `cp` command.